# Character permanently disappears when camera zooms in

Tags: unity

I am using ThirdPersonController and FreeLookCameraRig, both from the standard assets package. The camera generally follows the player fine but there is an issue when I move the camera very close to the player. When I do this, the character disappears, though it still behaves as though it is in the scene. For example, the xyz coords still show it as being in the scene and when it jumps, the camera still follows it.

Here's a visual explanation. Notice how the character disappears after about 5-10 seconds and doesn't come back.

(Note: the gif is too large to display here, so please see it on imgur. [http://i.imgur.com/PbMDlXD.gifv](https://i.imgur.com/PbMDlXD.gifv)).

The ThirdPersonController has Transform, Animator, CapsuleCollider, Third Person User Controller, and Third Person Character

The FreeLookCameraRig has Transform, Free Look Cam, and Protect Camera From Wall.

I have tried messing with many of these settings, but nothing has worked.

By the way, some of the course was created in Sketchup.

Comment: What are you seeing in the scene view when the character vanishes in the game view? Is the mesh still displayed there? Does anything funny happen to the player pawn's transform or other component values?

Comment: @DMGregory if I pause when the character is gone, I still can't see them. The transform values look normal. I can raise/lower the Y value, it has no effect.

Comment: @DMGregory I figured it out ... I had a custom rigid body defined on the Skeleton of the ThirdPersonController which was separating from the controller and free-falling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out ...  I had a rigid body defined on the Skeleton of the ThirdPersonController ... I needed to remove this. It was ending up separating from the ThirdPersonController and free-falling.